# Flutter - Sampling of an Audio File

Tags: flutter, audio, sample

Is it possible to split an audio file into individual samples in Flutter? Does anyone know a suitable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this simple plugin to import, cut and then export new audio files
https://pub.dev/packages/audiocutter

and then u can use this code:

```
import 'package:audiocutter/audiocutter.dart';


var start = 15.0;
var end = 25.5;

// Set The Path to You Your File To Import
var path = 'path/to/audio/file.mp3';

// Get path to cut file and do whatever you want with it.
var outputFilePath = await AudioCutter.cutAudio(path, start, end);
```